# Best practice for per-user strong parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, strong-parameters

I have an application with an `Order` model, connected to a `Purchaser` and a `Supplier`. The application is designed to limit who can create/update/destroy orders depending on their affiliation with these companies. (For instance, a member of a purchaser can create an order, but a member of a supplier cannot.)

I am enforcing these authorization rules at the controller level via strong parameters. My reasoning is twofold:

1. deferring them to a `before_save` callback (or other model logic) would remove parameter screening from the controller (where it belongs); and
2. even then, I'd have to pass additional information (namely, user identity) from the controller to the models to get it done, and that would lead to more tightly coupled classes.

Currently, my strong param logic looks like this:

```
def create_order_params
  params.require(:order).permit(:supplier_id, :purchaser_id, :notes)
    .merge({ placed_by: current_user })
end

def update_order_params
  params.require(:order).permit().tap do |p|
    p.merge!({ accepted_by: current_user }) if params.dig(:order, :accepted)
    if current_user.belongs_to?(@order.supplier)
      p.merge!(params[:order].permit(:discount, :discount_type))
    end
    if current_user.belongs_to?(@order.purchaser) && !@order.confirmed?
      p.merge!(params[:order].permit(:notes))
    end
  end
end
```

I think it's terribly unreadable. Is there a cleaner (or widely accepted) pattern for applying some authorization logic to strong parameters? Alternately, is this the wrong abstraction? Should I defer this authorization to the model after all?

Answer (score 1):

Since each type [Purchasers or Suppliers] has some authorities [or functions to do] and it is the only one who is authorized for such actions, then I suggest you place each type of tasks as  a method in either the [Purchasers or Suppliers] classes depending on which one has to do this method or task.

For example :

Since the Purchasers are only the ones who creates an Order so it would be reasonable to put a create order method in the Purchaser class, so that  each object has its responsibilities it needs to carry, and these methods can not be carried or accessed by any other entities since they do not have these methods encapsulated in them.

Thinking in an object oriented approach, and considering the 'single responsibility principle' , will lead you to having a better organizing and making the code more clean.

Comment: This is what I was thinking. If I understand correctly, this approach is not compatible with strong parameters, right? (_I.e.,_ the two classes may need different parameters, but since the controller is not distinguishing between them, it needs to pass any and all parameters that might be needed...)

Comment: yes, it is not related to strong parameters, it is related to the responsibilities for each class.
int the controller action you need to use strong parameters to ensure that no parameters are included other than the needed ones for you to use for creating or updating your tables (using create, update .. etc).

Comment: you can white list parameters in the controller, then define an object of the class type you want and delegate the parameters to the object's method that has the responsibility for carrying the task and completing the process.
you can do it the way you want as needed, I'm just giving you an example and everything is up to you about choosing how to implement everything and organize it.